# Rolling Granger Causality

Tags: r

I am using MSBVAR package in R to calculate Granger causality between two variables. The data and commands are same as used in the package:

```
data(IsraelPalestineConflict)
granger.test(IsraelPalestineConflict, p=6)
```

It gives following results:

```
              F-statistic  p-value
p2i -> i2p    17.63100     0.000000e+00
i2p -> p2i    10.91235     7.134737e-12
```

I want to apply a loop/rollapply with this function and want to save the results in a file. I tried like this after watching past answers on rollapply but as i am new to R so don't know how to make it work.

```
rollapply(zoo(IsraelPalestineConflict),width=1275,
          FUN = function(t) 
          { t = granger.test(IsraelPalestineConflict, p=6); 
          },
          by.column=FALSE, align="right")
```

But it gives the same results with first column replaced by years and i dont know how can i save the results of the F-statistics and P-values with rollapply.

```
             F-statistic  p-value
2003.8077    17.63100     0.000000e+00
2003.8269    10.91235     7.134737e-12
```

Kind answer is requested, please.

Comment: What doesn't work, exactly? Does the code you've posted result in an error, or does it just not produce the output you expect? Please edit your question to provide more details on exactly what is going wrong- it will make it more likely that someone can help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want this:

```
granger.test.c <- function(x) c(granger.test(x, p = 6))
rollapplyr(IsraelPalestineConflict, 1275, granger.test.c, by.column = FALSE )
```

This creates a list of the above for p = 2, 3, 4, 5:

```
granger.test.c <- function(x, p) c(granger.test(x, p = p))
p <- 2:5
roll <- function(p, DF) rollapplyr(DF, 1275, granger.test.c, by.column = FALSE, p = p )
L <- lapply(p, roll, DF = IsraelPalestineConflict)
names(L) <- p
```

Comment: @Grothendieck Dear Sir, Thanks a lot for the answer, i am really obliged. I just want to ask one more thing, if possible. As with your solution i get four forward steps (1275 to 1278). Is it possible that for each roll, i can change "p", already stored in another R object (p<-c(2,3,4,5). Thanks again.

Comment: @Grothendieck. Thanks again for the help. However, need your kind guidance as the new code runs the roll for each value of "p". I think my last comments were misleading. Sir, the 1st roll should use value 2 and the second roll use value 3 and like this. Although this code can be used and then i can pick the results for required "p" but kind guidance can reduce the working. Best wishes, Jawad

Comment: append a `p` column to your input and modify the function passed to rollapply to use that.

Comment: @Grothendieck. Tried a lot but no idea. Sir, waiting for your guidance, please.